# Are mmap and VirtualAlloc compliant with the C standard?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

As far as I understand the only way to get valid dereferenceable pointers in C is using `malloc` and `alloc` class of functions and taking address of global, static or local variables.

Now, say we stick to a particular platform and target - Windows on X86_64. 
The pointer type is internally a 64 bit unsigned integer and the CRT provides a library function called VirtualAlloc which allows the user to map pages into the Virtual Address space.

From Standard C point of view is this "Okay" or Undefined Behavior?
Because it seems that a simple program that uses these functions would dereference a pointer that doesn't come from `malloc` (or other mentioned valid sources).

Also there is the issue of an `unsigned long long` being casted to a `void*`
Or there is some provision in the standard that allows platform specific functions to have special meaning?

This might be very pedantic, but I am very confused.

Comment: This entire question seems to be predicated on your first paragraph - but where does that belief come from?

Comment: "Because it seems that a simple program that uses these functions would dereference a pointer that doesn't come from malloc (or other mentioned valid sources)" - what makes you think the standard forbids that?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth So how does one decide whether a pointer is valid (to dereference) or not. Does the standard recognize page mapping functions?

Comment: One can't (generally) inspect a pointer to determine whether it's valid or not.  Instead, you should know "by construction" - your program is written so that only valid pointers may propagate to where they're dereferenced.

Comment: "The pointer type is internally a 64 bit unsigned integer" - No. A pointer is not an integer type. Your CPU does not know about types. It operates on binary data in memory.

Comment: @Olaf I will rephrase - The pointer type is internally a set of 64 bits which has unsigned `+`, `-` operations defined on it

Comment: "From Standard C point of view is this "Okay" or Undefined Behavior" - standard C does not specify these functions. So how could it be anything else than undefined behaviour **with regard to the standard**. Finally: where is a pointer cast to `unsigned long long`? Please provide your code. It is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: To repeat: the CPU has no concept of types! - All recent CPUs at least. You confuse standard and implementation. Also you should learn more about CPUs and possibly read the standard before starting a discussion about the standard.

Comment: @Olaf, the CPU doesn't but the implementation does. So I can say that the implementation treats pointer type as an unsigned integer of 64 bits.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: **no**! Follow my advice, learn! And there is not **the** implementation. Neither is a pointer guaranteed 64 bits, nor have all pointers necessarily the same width, nor ...

Comment: @Olaf Please do not shout at people.

Comment: @Olaf I am talking about a particular implementation. Not *in general*. I wrote in the question I am talking about one implementation for Windows on the X86_64 architecture. There the pointers are of the same width and guaranteed to be 64 bit.

Comment: Olaf/Ajay - suggest you continue the discussion in chat, as it seems to be tangential to the actual question being asked.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: I did not say different. Maybe you read what constitutes a datatype.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Not really; OP has some missconceptions and confuses implementation and standard (see my 2nd comment and the answer by zwol). Sure this cannot be clarified here, that's why I recommended to get the basics right. Anyway, I agree further discussion is pointless.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Please don't ask people to use chat. Chat is a misfeature. The discussion of a question or answer belongs _with the question or answer_, i.e. in the comments.

Comment: @zwol - If it's a discussion about the question/answer, I agree.  The above seems to have devolved into a tangent, though.

Comment: @Olaf, I believe I have a reasonable understanding of how the CPU works. I also understand how the standard and implementations are different. I have the standard book marked and am in the process of reading it. During the course of reading I encounter such doubts and present them to a community that I believe can help me with. I would be glad if my doubts are taken in a constructive way and as an opportunity for learning however stupid and *basic* they may sound.

Comment: When C89 was written, the authors of the Standard didn't think the authors of implementations would need any particular encouragement to sensibly handle constructs that would have meaning on some platforms but not others.  If a program calls some function not defined by the Standard, the authors of the Standard would have no reason to say what such a function may or may not do, but if an underlying platform happens to defines a function that isn't defined by the Standard, a quality compiler suitable for system programming on that platform should generally make that available to a programmer...

Comment: ...without regard for whether the Standard would *require* such a behavior.

Comment: @supercat Makes sense, also adds to why certain things were left as Undefined Behavior and not just Implementation Defined behavior. Making it implementation defined would require it to be present on all implementations. Thanks!

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: The real semantic difference between UB and IDB are that IDB would requires that implementations define a behavior *even in cases where doing so would be unhelpful*, while UB does not.  Since implementations that can define useful behaviors should do so whether or not the Standard requires them to do so, the determining factor for whether something should be IDB vs UB is whether there might plausibly exist implementations where a requirement to define behavior could be unhelpful.  The notion that a compilers suitable for systems programming should actively assume...

Comment: ...that code won't rely upon any behaviors not mandated by the Standard seems to be a comparatively recent invention.  If 99.5% of platforms could at essentially zero cost guarantee that an action would always have one of two consequences, possibly chosen in Unspecified fashion, and in some situations either action would be equally acceptable, one should not expect code that expects that the action would have one of the expected behaviors to be portable to the 0.5% of systems where the guarantee might be expensive, but it should be portable to the other 99.5%.  Unfortunately, such thinking...

Comment: ...is no longer fashionable.

Comment: @supercat I will take some time to digest all that you said, thanks for the information :)

Comment: @supercat One example of the last part of your comment - A piece of code that relies on structs to have a certain padding should be considered to be portable to only those implementations that guarantee that padding strategy, and not portable to an implementation that doesn't guarantee it. One should realize this differentiation and not expect one to write codes that are strictly portable to all implementations. Is this a valid example?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: A more interesting scenario would occur with code that needs to access structure members which are known to be at the correct offset, and possibly even uses `offsetof` to confirm that they are.  In the name of "optimization", compilers have gotten more and more aggressive at breaking code that accesses storage through different structure types, even in cases that would have been considered uncontroversial uses of the Common Initial Sequence rule.

Comment: @These optimizations that you mention must be enabled only with very high optimization flags, since such  type of codes are very regularly seen in popular code bases. I can think of many instances in the Linux kernel itself that would break if these optimizations were enabled on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *any* library function that's not defined in the C standard, provokes undefined behavior—this is almost a tautology.  The behavior of such functions is not defined by the standard, ergo it must be undefined.

However, the implementation is perfectly free to define the behavior of any particular instance of UB as anything it likes; for example, implementations "targeting" Windows will define a library function `VirtualAlloc` that allocates memory much as `malloc` does, and returns a valid pointer to that memory.  And programs are perfectly free to rely on a particular implementation's definition.  Such programs, in the parlance of the standard, are *conforming* but not *strictly conforming*.

(A hypothetical implementation that defined `VirtualAlloc` to reformat the hard drive would still be a conforming implementation of C.   Windows programs should not be run on such an implementation, but conversely, programs that were written with the expectation that `VirtualAlloc` reformats the hard drive should not be run on Windows.)

Comment: Okay, what about the first argument to `VirtualAlloc` ? It is of type `LPVOID` or `void*` One will have to create this by casting an `unsigned long long` to `LPVOID`. How does that coform to the standard?

Comment: *Using any library function that's not defined in the C standard, provokes undefined behavior*, seriously? If this is true, how would you be able to use a custom library?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya If I remember correctly, the effect of casting an integer to a pointer type is _implementation-defined_ behavior, not undefined behavior, but anyway it's the same principle.  The implementation defines the behavior, and programs choose to rely on the implementation's definition.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès In a _strictly conforming_ program, which relies on nothing beyond what is defined by the standard, you can't.

Comment: @zwol, *The implementation chooses to define something that the standard chooses to leave undefined* - this is the key to my question. So independent of an implementation the behavior is undefined but with a particular implementation it becomes defined. We can think of it as an extension for a particular platform. Am I correct to say that

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Yes, that's it.

Comment: @zwol That makes sense. Thank you. So we can say this - The "Microsoft C compiler implementation" for Windows platform on X86_64 machines defines the behavior when an `unsigned long long` is casted to a `void*`.

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies my doubt.